# Distributing Python packages which depend on in-house common convenience libraries

Tags: python, distribution, packaging

I have a few Python packages that I would like to tidy up and publish on PyPI. These packages import a couple of Python modules I've written to augment or simplify certain operations (e.g., reading/writing from CSV files with headers by wrapping [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) functions), provide handy data structures, etc. Currently these modules are housed in the top-level directory that holds the code for my projects, and I rely on reaching them by having added that directory to my `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable. (Less than tidy, I know.)

By creating a separate package for these modules and uploading them on PyPI, I could mark such a package as a dependency for the packages I *actually* want to distribute. These convenience modules are, however, small and of limited use and interest, such that I don't think they warrant distributing as a separate package on PyPI. On the other hand, I am hesitant to copy these convenience modules (i.e., use `cp convenience_module.py projectX/.`) into each project directory, as this creates multiple copies of the same file both in the VCS repository housing my Python code and in the different source distribution tarballs I would post to PyPI. Is there an elegant solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say why you're hesitant to 'provide copies'. In general, I think a reasonable approach is to think about how you've set things up for yourself to use the convenience modules. Did you install them in site-packages (or equivalent), or did you just depend on them being in the directory you ran the code from? However you use the modules, is that situation ideal, or is there a way that would be nicer for you?

Start with that, and figure out how to automate it through setup.py, which lets you put things wherever you want on the system (though I strongly discourage abusing this capability).

Whether you distribute them as a tarball or with the package that needs them, you still have to maintain all of the files, so the only real question is whether you *intend* for those convenience modules to develop their own user communities with their own support requests, etc., or whether they're decidedly intended only for use in support of this other module.

If you intend those modules to be used only for the one module, include them in the package, perhaps in a 'utils' package inside the distribution. Otherwise you're just cluttering the index with things people might think are useful, but are really joined at the hip with something else that drives the changes and maintenance of them.

If you intend those modules to be generic, and intend to maintain them as such, and think they have use outside of supporting this module, distribute them separately.

Comment: I have re-worded my question; "provide copies" implied something different than what I mean, which is "to `cp` the file to multiple source trees." I definitely rely on having a modified `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable to ensure import of the modules works; they are not yet in their own Python package with a `setup.py` to themselves. Also, I don't plan to expand the functionality of these modules much; their contents are just a collection of functions I found I wanted to use repeatedly across a variety of projects.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, distributing these small packages via PyPI is only viable option. Yes, it clutters the index with near-useless packages, but its something that should be solved by PyPI maintainers, not package developers. Another alternative is to use stdlib's or other util packages data and functions rather than reinventing the wheel.

Just make sure you describe that utils package as such, or extend them in something more useful for others.

Comment: "Yes, it clutters the index with near-useless packages, but its something that should be solved by PyPI maintainers, not package developers." That sort of strikes me as not being a very good citizen to the Python community. Does PyPI even have maintainers? It seems like it's up to the developer to be a "good neighbor". On the other hand, if that's the way things are, then I can go with it.